# Why does my client not receive broadcastMessage with SignalR after jquery update (from 1.11.2, to 3.5.1)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I have a server client setup with C# and javascript with jquery. I wanted to update to the latest jquery (from 1.11.2 to 3.5.1). After update the site runs fine but signalR doesnt work anymore. SignalR version is 2.4.1. Connection starts up :

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            var dt = new Date();
            var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
            console.log("SignalR Connection successfully started " + time);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("SignalR Start Error");
        });
```

In the hub I send my message like this:

```
Clients.Group(GroupName).broadcastMessage(MessageName, Message);
```

As an initial step I add every client to a group with a unique name and connection ID, but even if I use `Clients.All.broadcastMessage(MessageName, Message);`
nothing happens. Meanwhile the hub receives calls from the client.
When client calls `messageHub.server.joinGroup(this.messageGroupName);` the server receives it.

```
public void JoinGroup(string GroupName)
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, GroupName);
        }
```

I handle incoming messages the following way in the client:

```
jQuery(function () {
            var messageHub = $.connection.messageHub;
            messageHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                switch (name) {
                    case "type1":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type2":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type3":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type4":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type5":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type6":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type7":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                }
                
            };
        })
```

Before switching jquery versions this way worked. Clients only received messages meant for them so the groups worked.

Thanks for reading and I appreciate any help.

Comment: any error in browser's console?

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider no errors

Answer (score 0):

Removing jQuery(function ())from around the incoming message code part. So it should simply be:

```
var messageHub = $.connection.messageHub;
            messageHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                switch (name) {
                    case "type1":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type2":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type3":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type4":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type5":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type6":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                    case "type7":
                        doStuff();
                        break;
                }
                
            };
```